# Laravel Excel, get data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I have problem with my Laravel Excel input API. I want data from my Excel save into my database, here's my code, my Excel, and my error:

```
Excel::selectSheets('CHS1')->load($uer->file, function($reader){
        $x = 1;
        $reader->limit(22);
        $cell = $reader->get();

        $data = [];

        $data['nama'] = $cell[3 - $x][5 - $x];
        $data['nim'] = $cell[4 - $x][5 - $x];
        $data['jk'] = $cell[5 - $x][5 - $x];
        $data['ttl'] = $cell[6 - $x][5 - $x];
        $data['program'] = $cell[3 - $x][8 - $x];
        $data['prodi'] = $cell[4 - $x][8 - $x];
        $data['gelar'] = $cell[5 - $x][8 - $x];
        $data['t_masuk'] = $cell[6 - $x][8 - $x];
        $data['t_keluar'] = $cell[7 - $x][8 - $x];

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $data[$key] = preg_replace('/^(\'?: ?)/', '', $value);
        }

        // Jenis kelamin
        $jk = [
            'Laki-laki' => 'l',
            'Perempuan' => 'p'
        ];
        $indexJk = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $data['jk']);
        $data['jk'] = $jk[$indexJk];

        // Bulan setting
        $month = [
            'Januari' => '01',
            'Febuari' => '02',
            'Maret' => '03',
            'April' => '04',
            'Mei' => '05',
            'Juni' => '06',
            'Juli' => '07',
            'Agustus' => '08',
            'September' => '09',
            'Oktober' => '10',
            'November' => '11',
            'Desember' => '12',
        ];
        $ttl = explode(',', $data['ttl']);

        $data['tempat'] = $ttl[0];

        $tanggal = preg_replace('/^ ?/', '', $ttl[1]);
        $tanggal = explode(' ', $tanggal);
        $tgl = $tanggal[0];
        $bln = $month[$tanggal[1]];
        $thn = $tanggal[2];
        $tanggal = $thn . '/' . $bln . '/' . $tgl;

        $data['tgl'] = Carbon::parse($tanggal)->format('Y:m:d');

        // Nilai
        $nilai = [];

        for($i = 9; $i < count($cell) - 2; $i++){
            $nilai['matkul'][$i] = $cell[$i][5 - $x];
        }

        for($i = 9; $i < count($cell) - 2; $i++){
            $nilai['smt'][$i] = $cell[$i][2 - $x];
        }
        for($i = 9; $i < count($cell) - 2; $i++){
            $kode = [
                'char' => $cell[$i][3 - $x],
                'num' => $cell[$i][4 - $x]
            ];
            $nilai['kode'][$i] = json_encode($kode);
        }
        for($i = 9; $i < count($cell) - 2; $i++){
            $nilai['nilai'][$i] = $cell[$i][6 - $x];
        }
        for($i = 9; $i < count($cell) - 2; $i++){
            $nilai['nilai_sk'][$i] = $cell[$i][7 - $x];
        }
        for($i = 9; $i < count($cell) - 2; $i++){
            $nilai['krd'][$i] = $cell[$i][8 - $x];
        }
        for($i = 9; $i < count($cell) - 2; $i++){
            $nilai['krp'][$i] = $cell[$i][9 - $x];
        }
        for($i = 9; $i < count($cell) - 2; $i++){
            $nilai['akw'][$i] = $cell[$i][10 - $x];
        }

        $newNilai = [];

        for($i = 9; $i < count($nilai['smt']) + 9; $i++){
            foreach ($nilai as $key => $value) {
                $newNilai[$i][$key] = $nilai[$key][$i];
            }
        }

        $mahasiswa = Nil_mahasiswas::where('nim', $data['nim'])->get()->first();
        $tbnilai;
        if($mahasiswa){

            $mahasiswa->nama    = $data['nama']; 
            $mahasiswa->nim     = $data['nim']; 
            $mahasiswa->jk      = $data['jk']; 
            $mahasiswa->tempat  = $data['tempat']; 
            $mahasiswa->tgl     = $data['tgl']; 
            $mahasiswa->program = $data['program']; 
            $mahasiswa->prodi   = $data['prodi']; 
            $mahasiswa->gelar   = $data['gelar']; 
            $mahasiswa->t_masuk = $data['t_masuk']; 
            $mahasiswa->t_keluar= $data['t_keluar']; 

            $mahasiswa->save();

            $id_mahasiswa = $mahasiswa->id;

            $tbnilai = Nilais::where('id_mahasiswa', $id_mahasiswa)->get(); 

            for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++){
                $nilai = $newNilai[$i+9];
                $tbnilai = Nilais::where('id_mahasiswa', $id_mahasiswa)->get()[$i];
                $tbnilai->delete();
                CommonController::createNilai($tbnilai, $nilai, $id_mahasiswa);
            }
        }else{
            Nil_mahasiswas::create([
                'nama'  => $data['nama'],
                'nim'   => $data['nim'],
                'jk'    => $data['jk'],
                'tempat'=> $data['tempat'],
                'tgl'   => $data['tgl'],
                'program'=> $data['program'],
                'prodi' => $data['prodi'],
                'gelar' => $data['gelar'],
                't_masuk'=> $data['t_masuk'],
                't_keluar'=> $data['t_keluar']
            ]);

            $mahasiswa = Nil_mahasiswas::where('nim', $data['nim'])->get()->first();
            $id_mahasiswa = $mahasiswa->id;

            for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++){
                $nilai = $newNilai[$i+9];
                CommonController::createNilai(new Nilais, $nilai, $id_mahasiswa);
            }

        }

    });
```

And this is what my Excel looks like:

[image]

Comment: You received the notification about your post being mostly code, because it is. What it's really hinting towards is the fact that there's a minimal description of the problem. What's the real issue? What do you need help with? Are there any errors? Can we see the Stack Trace if there are Errors? Also, your variables aren't in english, so we have no idea what they really mean.